# Can't log in to my user on Mojave with Filevault enabled!

Tags: macos, mac, mojave, filevault

I am having issues with my user account in Mojave. The apple support reps and online forums signal that it is due to Filevault.

Essentially my MacBook froze one day (beachball) and I powered off. When I restarted, I was taken to a separate user account after I logged into my standard user. From there, I couldn't get in.

So I booted in recovery mode and removed the `.AppleSetupDone` from the `Macintosh HD/var/db/` folder.

Once I did I had to go through OSX set up assistant then create a new admin. When I got in, I could see my other original user and log out to log back into it.

A few days later it happened again, this time I did the same thing removing `.AppleSetupDone`, restarting, and creating a new user. But this time, I did not see my original user anymore in system preferences.

I tried to repair disk permissions, create the same user from system preferences, and even clear the `.AppleSetupDone` once again. Nothing was working. I do have Filevault enabled, but I was not able to click the "Enable users..." button. It wasn't working.

I can see my user folder in my `Users/` directory, but I am not able to log in.

Any ideas on how to regain access to the original user and have it show up in system preferences?